# how do i remove line breakes from a text file in python so its easier to work with

Tags: python, printing, line-breaks, python-3.8

I'm using python 3.8. My code still prints with line breaks. I have tried functions `strip()`, `rstrip()` and `replace()`.

This is one version of my code:

```
    with open('code.txt', 'r') as c:
        code = c.readlines()
    code = ''.join(code)

    print(code.replace("/n", ""))
```

code.txt is

```
    hello
    there
```

its printing

```
    hello
    there
```

but i want it to print

```
    hellothere
```

Comment: If you want to make the `replace` method work, a linebreak is `\n`, not `/n`.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using the `.strip()` method

```
with open('code.txt', 'r') as c:
    code = [i.strip() for i in c.readlines()]
code = ''.join(code)
```

```
>>> code
helloworld
```

Comment: no problem, if you liked the answer you can accept it for future users by clicking the checkmark. Thanks for asking and happy coding!